# Understanding Erdos' Proof on Weird Number Density

Tags: number-theory, asymptotics

[In this 1974 paper,](https://old.renyi.hu/~p_erdos/1974-24.pdf) Paul Erdos proves that the set of weird numbers has positive density in the natural numbers.

> THEOREM 5. The density of weird numbers is positive .
>   Proof. If $n$ is weird, then let $\epsilon_n$be as in the proof of the lemma. Now, by the
>   lemma, if $t$ is an integer and $a-(t)/t < 1 + \epsilon_n$ then $nt$ is weird . But the density of the
>   integers $t$ with $Q(t)/t < 1 + \epsilon_n$ is positive for any $\epsilon_n > 0$.
>   Actually, we proved a slightly stronger result . If $n$ is weird, then the density of
>   {$m; n I m$ and $m$ is weird} is positive .

The lemma he is referring to in his proof is the following.

> LEMMA. If $n$ is weird, then there is an $\epsilon_n > 0$ such that $nt$ is weird if
>   $$\sum_{d|t}{\frac{1}{d}}<1+\epsilon_n$$

I understand the heuristics behind this theorem, it is easy to make more weird numbers from multiples of other weird numbers, however, I am confused about the following statement.

> But the density of the
>   integers $t$ with $Q(t)/t < 1 + \epsilon_n$ is positive for any $\epsilon_n > 0$.

Could someone show/explain to me where this statement comes from? It seems to be the crux of the proof, however, I don't see where it comes from.

Thank you in advance.